# Decreasing column values with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to decrease values in a column. The following code

```
df['ID'] = df.index
df.loc[df['ID'].astype(int)] -= 1
```

Should convert

```
   ID  Process ID Name     Time
0   0         NaN  NaN  msecond
1   1     32434.0   X1      1.4
2   2     32434.0   X2      1.3
```

to

```
   ID  Process ID Name     Time
0  -1         NaN  NaN  msecond
1   0     32434.0   X1      1.4
2   1     32434.0   X2      1.3
```

How can I fix that? I should keep the first line because of the code I have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract `ID` only:

```
#if necessary convert to integers
#df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)
df['ID'] -= 1
```

Or maybe:

```
df['ID'] = df.index - 1
```

For first column:

```
df.insert(0, 'ID', df.index - 1)
```